# How to cut the screen?

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, calculator

I made my own simple calculator but I want to cut it, Can anyone help how do it?

Following is my pic where I want to cut this.

> [image]

I used:

`android:layout_width="fill_parent"`

`android:layout_height="wrap_content"`

But it's not working.pls help!

Here is my source code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:background="#cccccc"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:padding="15dp"/>

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/tableID"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp">

        <TableRow>
             <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn7"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="7"/>

             <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn8"
                android:text="8"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>

             <Button
                 android:id="@+id/btn9"
                 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:text="9"
                 android:layout_weight="1"/>

             <Button
                 android:id="@+id/btndiv"
                 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:text="÷"
                 android:layout_weight="1"/>     
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn4"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="4"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn5"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="5"
               android:layout_weight="1"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn6"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="6"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnx"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="x"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>

       </TableRow>
       <TableRow>
           <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="1"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>

           <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn2"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="2"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>

           <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn3"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="3"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>

           <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnsub"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="-"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>
           </TableRow>
           <TableRow>

               <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn0"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="0"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>

               <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnc"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="C"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>

               <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnequal"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="="
                android:layout_weight="1"/>

               <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnadd"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="+"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>

           </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You can't just "cut" the screen. Maybe try centering your calculator vertically in the center of the screen.

Comment: Try Using Window Activity.

Comment: Solution is Either you have to Increase your button size Or you have to add Something in Footer.

Comment: What do you mean by cut?

Comment: @insomniac I provided a pic, check this out!

Comment: @PrashantMishra how to use `Window Activity`?

Comment: you cant cut your screen,

Comment: any better idea? that could be hide?

Comment: Study it you will find many examples about it on internet. and i think it will fulfill ur requirement..

Comment: you can display your activity as a dialog......

Comment: @user3243147 how?? can you help me??

Comment: yea sure..
see  answer!!

Answer (score 0):

your main Linear Layout change like this change this line `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`

```
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#ff00ff00"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:background="#cccccc"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:padding="15dp" />

<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/tableID"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp" >

    <TableRow>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn7"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="7" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn8"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="8" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn9"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="9" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btndiv"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="÷" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn4"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="4" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn5"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="5" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn6"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="6" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnx"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="x" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="2" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn3"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="3" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnsub"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="-" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn0"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="0" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnc"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="C" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnequal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="=" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnadd"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="+" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>

 </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.Dialog.NoActionBar"
```

by adding this line to your manifest

```
 <activity
            android:name=".DemoActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.Dialog.NoActionBar" >
```

Or Try this in your xml:-

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="30dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:background="#cccccc"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:padding="15dp" />

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/tableID"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp" >

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn7"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="7" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn8"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="8" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn9"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="9" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btndiv"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="÷" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn4"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="4" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn5"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="5" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn6"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="6" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnx"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="x" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="1" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn2"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="2" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn3"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="3" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnsub"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="-" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn0"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="0" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnc"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="C" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnequal"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="=" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnadd"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="+" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
```